Do two bodies with the same mass but different volumes, exert the same gravitational pull?
Asking this strictly from GR, not Newtonian gravity. I am not well versed with GR, so let me know if my question fundamentally misunderstood the concepts of GR, but if there are two independent bodies, with the exact same mass, but with noticeable differences in their volumes, would a third observer experience the same gravitational pull from both the objects?

Are you assuming that they have spherically-symmetric mass distributions? A cube and a ball of the same mass create different gravity.

Are they charged? Rotating? On top of what Ghoster asked. But far enough away, basically yes.

Since it is not true in NG, and NG is a limit of GR, it cannot be true in GR.

Is the observer at equal distances from the centres of the objects? Or is the observer on the surface of the objects?

In the simplest case where the body is spherically symmetric, uncharged and non-rotating the geometry outside the body is given by the Schwarzschild metric and depends only on the mass. This is Birkhoff's theorem. So two bodies with the same mass but different volumes will create the same geometry, and therefore the same gravitational field, everywhere outside their surface.
This does not apply to a rotating body as the Kerr metric applies only when the body is a black hole and is not the same a the exterior metric of a rotating non-black hole. See The Kerr metric applied to a solid rotating body for more on this. However we should inject a note of realism and point out that assuming there are no differences in Newtonian gravity (such as different quadrupole moments) any differences in GR will be immeasurably small except in extreme cases.

According to General Relativity, the spacetime curvature around a body with mass(or energy) depends upon the density (either of energy or of mass corresponding to the situation) of the body. And the curvature is directly proportional to the curvature. So considering the case you have given here , the body with lower volume curves the local spacetime around it more than the one with higher volume thus exerts a higher "gravitational force".(I am putting this in quotes since there is nothing as gravitational force only the spacetime curvature)
Hope it is clear.

(I have answered assuming the masses are of same geometry, not charged and not rotating.)

the curvature is directly proportional to the curvature Typo?

According to General Relativity, the spacetime curvature around a body with mass(or energy) depends upon the density (either of energy or of mass corresponding to the situation) of the body. That’s an oversimplification. The energy-momentum-stress tensor on the right side of the Einstein field equations involves more than the energy density or the mass density.

Hope it is clear. Have a good day! Answers on this site, like questions, should not contain chit-chat. Just the physics is sufficient.

@Ghoster There's a clear difference between "chit-chat" and basic politeness, which is what this answer contains. Your culture may not value politeness, but many cultures do.

@gandalf61 Cultures have nothing to do with it. The Tour says “This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.” You may think that means putting “Have a good day!” in an answer is fine, but I think you’re 100% wrong. This site aims to be like a physics encyclopedia in Q&A format. Encyclopedia articles do not end with “Have a good day!” or “Hope it is clear”.

@gandalf61 When I have a chance I’ll post a question on Physics Meta about this so that we know whether you’re right or I’m right about the site policy on this.

@Ghoster Site policy on politeness is very clear: "Always be polite and have fun" - https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Politeness is not "chit-chat".

@gandalf61 Polite chit-chat is still banned chat-chat. See Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts? If this post on the mother Meta doesn’t convince you, then I’ll take the issue to Physics Meta.

@gandalf61 I routinely edit this stuff out and have never had such an edit rejected.

Don't trigger Ghoster, or else he'll become the Ghost Rider and will come for you @gandalf61

@gandalf61 "No chit-chat" vs. "Always be polite"

Sorry @Ghoster since I am new to this site I am not well aware of the policies ... I will see that this kind of things will not be repeated from my side.
